# Concentration of the value of times Markov Chain visits a certain state

Tags: markov-chains, expected-value, variance, concentration-of-measure

I have a 2-state Markov chain with the following transition matrix

${\displaystyle  P={\begin{bmatrix}1-p&p\\1&0\end{bmatrix}} }$,
where $0 < p < 1$.

Initially, we are in State 1.

Let $X_n$ be the number of times State 2 is visited by time $n$.

I would like to have some concentration inequality for $X_n$ deviating from it's expected value.

That is something like this:

$$
P(|X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n]| > \mathbb{E}[X_n]) < f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),
$$

where $f$ is, say, some polynomial.

Does such an inequality hold? If yes, what would be a function $f$?